# Counting the number of lines pass through exactly $√n$ points.

Tags: combinatorics, computational-geometry

I need to prove the following:

> Let $S$ be a set of $n$ points in the plane, and let t be the number
> of lines that pass through exactly $√n$ points of S. Prove that $t =
>  O( √ n)$.

I am pretty new to combinatorics.

Why wouldn't be answer simply $t = √ n$?

In the worst case, Were gonna need a line for each of the $√ n$ Points.

Comment: Consider a square pattern on $n$ points where $n$ is a perfect square. Like $(\frac{i}{\sqrt{n}},\frac{j}{\sqrt{n}})$ as $i,j$ go from $1$ to $\sqrt{n}$. There are the $\sqrt{n}$ horizontal lines, the $\sqrt{n}$ vertical lines and some diagonal lines. $t > \sqrt{n}$, but it is still true that $t \leq 3 \sqrt{n}$. So if you take this sequence as an example you see that $t$ can't be in $O(f(n))$ for $f$ that grows slower than $\sqrt{n}$. The next step is to show there are no other sequence of shapes for which $t$ grows even faster. That this square arrangement achieves that maximum growth rate.

Comment: Maybe, there are so many diagonal lines that you can always get $n^{2/3}$ lines.  Prove that can't happen.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question (not proving the $O(\sqrt{n})$ itself, it is "why not $t=\sqrt{n}$" or even "why not $t\le\sqrt{n}$"), there are a lot of examples that $t\le\sqrt{n}$ won't hold: think about a $t\times t$ square grid, and there are $t$ horizonal lines and $t$ vertical lines, and thus $2t=2\sqrt{n}$ lines.

However, as @AHusain said, $t\le 3\sqrt{n}$, is also not correct, too. Think about the counterexample: nine points $(-2,1),(0,1),(2,1),(-1,0),(0,0),(1,0),(-2,-1),(0,-1),(2,-1)$ and there are ten such lines: $y=1,y=0,y=-1,x=0,x=2y,x=-2y,y=x+1,y=x-1,y=-x+1,y=-x-1$.

(Maybe this answer is better to be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation...)

Comment: I was referring to the regular square pattern there. There were $t=\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n} + d$ lines meeting the criterion. $\sqrt{n}$ for vertical and horizontal and then some $d$ for anything that was not parallel with one of the sides that still managed to go through exactly $\sqrt{n}$ of the points. The counterexample is not such a regular pattern.