# Arrange $n$ points in the plane such that such that the number of lines pass through exactly $\sqrt{n}$ will be maximized.

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, computational-geometry

Given a number $n$ which is a perfect square, define a set of $n$ points in the plane, such that the number of lines passing through exactly $\sqrt{n}$ points will be maximized.

My idea:

Arrange the points as a square lattice, then you will have $2\sqrt{n} + 2$ lines pass thru $\sqrt{n}$ points (Two diagonals, $\sqrt{n}$ horizonal and $\sqrt{n}$ vertical).

[image]

I was thinking about induction, But was not able to go further.

I need some assistance to prove that In order to achieve the maximum, the points must be arranged as a square lattice, I've been sitting on it for a while now.

Comment: It is not always true that a square grid attains the maximum. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4360388) to a closely related question shows how to get $10$ lines with $9$ points, where a square grid would only get $8$ lines.

Comment: Here are sixteen points which form 15 lines of four; a square grid would only achieve 10 lines. https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKPZ5.png